# How can I start Appium server to test website in android emulator?

Tags: android, appium, robotframework, web-testing

I need to start a robot framework test for the website by using the android emulator. For these reasons, I need to start appium server which should work with the android emulator in adv manager. I'm already tried this on windows and Ubuntu and have 2 problems:
1 - windows) starting the session failed with the next problem: can't find adb.exe  and asked me "Do you have Android Build Tools installed at <....some paths here>?"
p.s: (android and java paths are correctly configured)
2 - ubuntu) almost the same as windows problems, but appium can't find the ANDROID and Java environment [you can see in screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrChO.png). I'm already set variables twice, but it didn't help. finally, appium cant find some packages which I already installed.

Comment: It won't work until you have PASS an Appium-Doctor checking without Error. It's clearly said you haven't ANDROID_HOME in the system env.

Comment: @adrenalineWest, the env was crealy defined. After 2 days it's started working by its own whithout any chenges from me